# JavaScript: Access variables created by an Click-Event outside the Scope of .addEventlistener()

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I want to update Variables outside an Click-Eventlistener.

*The following is just demo-code, its not intended to work or anything, just to demonstrate my problem*.

---

**Class**

```
 class test {
    constructor() {
        // SOMETHING
    }
    
    get a() {//DOSTH};
    get b() {//DOSTH};
```

**Button - Part**

```
applyBtn.addEventListener('click', () {
    const a1 = testArr.a;
    const b1 = testArr.b;
});

console.log(a1);
console.log(b1);
```

Of course, the *console.log(a1)* e.G. is executed immediately which leads to nothing being logged. This makes completely sense, since I get *a1* and *b1* **after** the button is clicked.

---

**My Question**

How do I create code (e.g. a function or a class) that works after the Button is clicked with the condition that it should **not be inside** of the *addEventlistener()* functionality?

I have something like the Promise-Technique in my mind by using a *then()*.

---

**Edit*

*Background-Information*

My goal is to create a new class that uses *a1* and *a2*
and sends these variables to  another file (a python file, I am using ChildProcesses of NodeJS for doing so).

I would like to keep a clean code structure which implements the OOP principle as most as possible, which is why I do not want to add this functionality inside of the *addEventListener()*.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. WHY do you want to access a1 outside the eventListener? You can define the var outside all functions as a global var and then it will be filled after a click has set it

Comment: ^ I completely agree. Just to add to the above: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: You can use closures

Comment: @VLAZ I added some background Information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try closures. With a function closure you can store data in a separate scope, and share it only where necessary.

```
const click = () => {
  let count = 1

  return () => count++
}

const incrementCount = click()
const anotherIncrementCount = click()

console.log(incrementCount()) // 1
console.log(incrementCount()) // 2
console.log(incrementCount()) // 3
console.log(anotherIncrementCount()) // 1
```

Comment: i don´t see how i can implement the addEventListener-Functionality here?

Comment: @ArgentHo [something like this](https://jsbin.com/sijodux/edit?html,js,console,output). Click the Click Me button several times then you can see the count by using How Many.

Comment: @VLAZ So, in fact this problem is simply solved by providing a Callback-Function inside of the addEventListener. thanks!